# How to remove partition and extend macOS partition size in macOS High Sierra?

Tags: mac, partitioning, boot-camp, storage, disk-utility

On my Mac, I had a BootCamp partition set up that I deleted using Disk Utility. Here's what the current setup looks like:

[image]

And here it is in the Partition dialog:

[image]

Dragging the control on the pi chart only reduces the size of the macOS partition, it does not increase it.

How do I fix my macOS partition to use the entire disk space ?

Comment: You went wrong at "deleted using Disk Utility" You should have used Boot Camp. You now need either some very good terminal chops [I've seen it done but wouldn't know where to start], or a partition utility like [Paragon Hard Disk Manager](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/hdm-mac/) Basically, you have another partition in the way of your expansion.

Comment: Ugh... forget that - you're using APFS. All bets are off. Backup, wipe the entire disk, restore. ...or try this, but you're on your own using a beta OS & file system - https://www.macobserver.com/tips/deep-dive/resize-your-apfs-container/